# script to move all files into one folder

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I would like to move all folders under `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` into one folder
1- I created the folder

```
@echo off   
md Personal
pause
```

2- I am trying to move all the files in Documents to one folder --> personal

```
@echo off
Move "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" *.* "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Personal"
pause
```

but it's not working?
`%USERPROFILE%\Documents` I need to send it to 10 users to run the batch file-

your help would be appreciated thank you

Tameem

Comment: Your [move](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html) command has three parameters. One too much...

Comment: looks like this answer might help: https://superuser.com/questions/1152895/powershell-copy-item-recursively-but-dont-include-folder-name

Comment: Hello @phil Ninan, thanks for the link.. the copy part works. but I have issue with move

Comment: You tagged powershell but using batch file. Are you trying to use powershell? What have you tried with powershell

Comment: When you say, *not working*, what's the error?

Comment: **Which do you want?** Both your title and item `2.` are moving files, whilst the opening sentence speaks of moving folders!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have this tagged as PowerShell, here is the PowerShell solution.

```
# Create folder
New-Item -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\Personal" -ItemType Directory
# Move all files from Documents to Personal
Get-ChildItem -File "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\" | Move-Item -Destination "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\Personal"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this PS command will not work if there is multiple login, is there a command to move document for the current login user,

Comment: it's working great the only think left- it move only files- and it keeps the folders

Comment: Got it to Work - I just changed -Files to Get-ChildItem -Path
And it's working now- I can move folders thank you-